# Amazon CloudWatch Agent won't push logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to push logs from a RHEL EC2 Instance to CloudWatch. I created an Ansible role to install the cloudwatch agent. When i run `systemctl status amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service` it says it is running, however nothing is appearing in cloudwatch. The amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log is showing the following error:

```
[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Retried 114 time, going to sleep 46.304092322s before retrying.
[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received when sending logs to <log-group>/<log-stream>: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, .
EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>

    status code: 404, request id: 
[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Retried 110 time, going to sleep 53.955265612s before retrying.
```

However, I am able to use the aws cli to push logs using the following command
`aws logs put-log-event --log-group-name <log-group> --log-stream-name <log-stream> --log-events timestamp=<xxxxxxxxxxxx>,message="testing aws cli"`

originally I thought it was an issue with the instance not being able to get AWS credentials, however if I can push to the log group with the cli this clearly isn't the case. Am i missing something in my CloudWatch configuration that could be causing this error?

Inside common-config.toml I have a proxy server set.

I have tried setting the profile to AmazonCloudWatchAgent, however I have not specified a credential file as I am unable to include credentials on the instance due to being prohibited by my employer.
If i set the profile to AmazonCloudWatchAgent, (with the below config):

```
# This common-config is used to configure items used for both ssm and cloudwatch access


## Configuration for shared credential.
## Default credential strategy will be used if it is absent here:
##  Instance role is used for EC2 case by default.
##  AmazonCloudWatchAgent profile is used for onPremise case by default.
[credentials]
   shared_credential_profile = "AmazonCloudWatchAgent"
#   shared_credential_file = "{file_name}"


## Configuration for proxy.
## System-wide environment-variable will be read if it is absent here.
## i.e. HTTP_PROXY/http_proxy; HTTPS_PROXY/https_proxy; NO_PROXY/no_proxy
## Note: system-wide environment-variable is not accessible when using ssm run-command.
## Absent in both here and environment-variable means no proxy will be used.
  [proxy]
     http_proxy = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx"
     https_proxy = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx"
#    no_proxy = "{domain}"

# [ssl]
#    ca_bundle_path = "{ca_bundle_file_path}"
```

then I get the following error:

```
[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Retried 4 time, going to sleep 1.70156025s before retrying.
[outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received when sending logs to <log-group>/<log-stream>: SharedCredsLoad: failed to load shared credentials file
caused by: FailedRead: unable to open file
caused by: open /root/.aws/credentials: no such file or directory
```

Comment: can you check which  IAM entity is used for CLI, since that is working?
`aws sts get-caller-identity`. Is it an IAM role or configured credentials? Maybe try explicitly copying the credentials file to the`/root/.aws` folder. Maybe issues with linux user and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IAM role, which allows for:

- CloudWatchFullAccess
- AmazonSSMFullAccess

..then add this to your EC2 instance - Security details - IAM Role.

Also you must explicitly set your (export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID's).